# close and flush the stream after an operation timed out

Tags: c#, timeout, filestream, roslyn

I have a function that writes to a file. The function is taken as a string and dynamically executed using Roslyn Emit API (so I am not sure how to get access to the stream object on which I can invoke the close and flush method)

```
using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = 
        new System.IO.StreamWriter(path))
    {
            // some code
    }
```

The problem is sometimes the function can end up with a dead loop. So I set a time out on the execution.

```
var task = Task.Run(() => execution);
        if (task.Wait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)))
            return task.Result;
        else
```

The question how do I clean up the stream left by the dead loop because next round I am executing the function to write the file again. It gives me "the process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process".

Comment: `Task.Wait()` just monitors the task, if it exits for any reason (return successfully, threw an exception) within the timeout then it returns `true`, otherwise `false`. So I'm assuming your `using` statement never goes through the `finally` because the task never actually ends. You did not "set a timeout on execution", to do that the function called by the task needs to have its own "dead loop" detection, such as: it needs to monitor a cancel token passed in, or you need to pass in a timeout so it can time itself out and exit (at which point your `using` will flush the stream to the file).

Comment: I can not set a timeout on execution because they are given as constant string all I do is run them dynamically through Roslyn Emit API

Comment: Sorry I don't know Roslyn Emit API. Who is giving you the "constant string"? They need to fix their code and pass you a better string because currently it is prone to unrecoverable infinite loops. Unless you can modify the code you are executing then there is no way to "clean up the stream left by the dead loop". Well, you could attempt to get the code to throw an exception somehow after the timeout, then the `using` will take care of things for you, but I assume that's going to be hard or impossible to do.

Comment: Can you pass a `CancellationToken` to that function and assume that it will honor when it's cancelled? Or maybe you can pass the `Stream` to the function?